# Pass values from children to parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have two components :

- The first one is the parent Component which is a usual React Component.
- The second one is the child which is a functional component.

I want to pass the value of **Titles** (in the child state) to the parent Component. Here is my code of **Child Component**:

```
        export default function ChildApp(props) {

        const  [titles,setTitles] = React.useState("")

          return (

           <Button title="submit" onPress={()=>setTitles("asma")}/>

               );
             }
```

And here is my **Parent Component** :

```
       this.state = { titles:"foo"} 
       setTitles = titles => this.setState({ titles })

       // i need the value of Titles to be set in state 
        export default class ParentApp extends Component {
       const titles = this.state.titles
           <ChildApp titles={titles} setTitles={this.setTitles} />
         }
```

It seems easy to do but it's the first time for me working with functional components.
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React is all about data flowing down in the components tree. If you want your `Child` to be able to show and/or modify a shared state between `Child` and `Parent` you should [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and pass it down via `props` to it's `children`

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const [title, settitle] = useState('foo')

    return <Child title={title} setTitle={setTitle} />
}


const Child = ({ title, setTitle}) =>{
     return <input value={title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
}
```

In class based components

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    state = { title: '' }

    setTitle = title => this.setState({ title })

    render(){
        const { title } = this.state
        return <Child title={title} setTitle={this.setTitle} />
    }
}


class Child extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const { title, setTitle } = this.props
        return <input value={value} setTitle={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
    }
}
```

Comment: @Asma Destrucutre the ````props```` passed to a functional component is a good pattern, as @Dupocas wrote in his answer. So instead you have  to write````props.title```` to access your data, you can just type````title````.

Comment: i'm sorry i can't get it . should i convert my parent component to a functional one ?

Comment: No need. It's just in my example. I'll update the answer showing how it works in class based components

Comment: i get it now just in child you have to put props.setTitle(e.target.value) to make it work . Thank you so much