# How to pass a child method to a parend component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to use a method from a child component in to it's parent component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass values from functional component to React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273144/pass-values-from-functional-component-to-react-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, no.
React it is a library build from up to down and without full data flow policy.

I not sure what you try to achieve and send but think about one of those solutions:

1. Return at the child the method you want to send to the parent
2. Create a const and a function able to change the const at the parent,  send them (at least the function) as props to the child
3. Use library such Redux to manage the whole app state, then you can manipulate it at the child and changes will affect the parent

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. I'm new to React so I haven't figured out how everything works yet. 

I rearranged the components, and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pattern you should really try to avoid, but if you find yourself needing to do it, you can create a "setter" function in the parent, and pass it to the child using props.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      childFunction: null,
    };
  }

  setChildFunction(childFunction){
    this.setState({
      childFunction: childFunction,
    )}
  }

  useChildFunction(){
    if(this.state.childFunction){
      this.state.childFunction();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent" onClick={this.useChildFunction.bind(this)}>
       <Child setChildFunction={this.setChildFunction.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.setChildFunction(this.childFunction.bind(this));
  }

  childFunction(){
    //do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="child" /> 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way i.e. by using a ref, but this is antipattern.

```js
const App = () => {
  const r = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => r.current()}>add</button>
      <Child r={r}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = ({r}) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  r.current = () => setCount(count + 1);
  return (
    <p>{count}</p>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```