# How can I import data from the child container to the parent container in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent-child

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import NameContainer from '../nameContainer/index'


export default class Vishal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: "This is the data"
        }
    }

      render() {
          return(
              <div>
                <p>My name is Vishal</p>
              </div>
          )
      }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class NameContainer extends Component {

}
```

How can I use a callback function and `import from the child component`? Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273144/pass-values-from-functional-component-to-react-component/58273209#58273209

Comment: Hi, I want to print the data and not enter it in a textfield. Just want the parent component to take data from the child component through a callback function and print the same.

Answer (score 1):

This violates the top-down philosophy of react and any sort of way to hijack that is probably not the direction you want to go.

What I think you mean to do is have state in the parent container, and allow the child to display and update that state.

i.e Parent.JS

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class NameContainer extends Component {
    this.state = { name: 'Vishal' }

handleChange = this.setState({name: event.target.value}) 

render() { 
    return (
          <Vishal name={this.state.name} handleChange={this.handleChange} />     )}
```

then in child js // Vishal.js

```
 { ...boilerplate }
 handleChange = this.props.handleChange; // and e.g a button or textfield to allow the user to update the name.

 render() { 
     return ( {this.props.name}) }}
```

this will display the stateful data of name (initalized as 'Vishal') from Parent.js in the child component, Vishal.js

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just want the parent component to take data from the child component and print the data without having a textfield. Could you please help?

Comment: Yes, the code I wrote should allow you to do that but you have parent and child switched. you cannot have child hold the state and tell the parent what state is without engaging in some very confusing contortions --> probably not what you want.

Comment: Okay thanks. So does this mean child cannot push data to parent component?

Comment: you can update the parent state from the child. you can display the parent's state in the child. you can have the child have it's own state. you can do more things beyond this but I would strongly discourage you from doing this. this is going to make your example way too confusing

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Much appreciated.