# Callback function from parent to child in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a parent `App` and a child component `Login`. In the `Login` component, the user can login properly, and I can store the user details in `setState`. But I want to pass this state to the parent `App` through a callback function from the parent through the function named `userState`.

Here is the parent `App`:

```
const { BrowserRouter, Link, Switch, Route, browserHistory } = ReactRouterDOM;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentUser: ""
    }
  }
  userState = (user) => {
    this.setState = {
      currentUser: user
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/someroute1">
              <Someroute1 />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login">
              <Login userState={this.userState} currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/route2">
              <Someroute2 />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector(".container"));
```

Here is the child `Login`:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: "",
            currentUser: this.props.currentUser
        }
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value })
    }
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch("/sessions", {
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(loggedInUser => {
                return loggedInUser.json();
            }).then(jsonedUser => {
                this.props.userState(jsonedUser); // <- this doesn't seem to work
                console.log('Current User is:', this.state.currentUser) // <- this.state.currentUser is blank
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

I have checked out this tutorial https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17 and checked out a lot of answers from stackoverflow, but somehow my callback function doesn't do anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273144/pass-values-from-functional-component-to-react-component/58273209#58273209) help you?

Comment: In your `userState` method in the parent component, you shouldn't assign value to `this.setState` but instead use `this.setState` as a method fir setting state like this: `this.setState({currentUser: user})`. More about `setState` method [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Answer (score 1):

This might help you 
**Parent**

```
import Child from '../child.js';

class Parent extends Component {

 getValue = (data) =>{
  //Login data
  console.log(data);
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    <Child getValue={this.getValue} />
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

**Child**

```
 class Child extends Component {

 onLogin = () =>{
  this.props.getValue('any data to parent here');
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    <button onClick={()=>this.onLogin}>Login</button>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the error you are receiving.

First off, Parent JS looks great!

in childJS there are some issues, they begin right here:

```
    this.state = {
    ...  
    currentUser: this.props.currentUser
}
```

and presumably they follow down into the rest of the component (i.e where you are displaying what the user sees).

What you need to do is keep the data flow consistent. ChildJS does not need state, it just needs to show the parent state (which is passed down by props).

ParentJS (state: user, setState) =>

Child JS will then be: render() { return ( {currentUser} )}
with say