# React, pass data from child to parent with props

Tags: reactjs

I have two components:

In a parent component:

```
handleSubmit= (val) => {
    console.log(val)//hello
    console.log("but I also needs the value of indexTab here, I just have the parameter val")
    console.log(indexTab) <---
}

render() {
    const val =" hello"

    return(
        <Child
            handleOnSubmit = {() => this.handleSubmit(val)}
            etc...
```

In Child I have:

```
class Child extends Component<Props> {

  render() {

    const { indexTab } = this.props;

    return (<Button onClick={handleSubmit}> {indexTab !== 2 ? "Save 0 or 1" : "Save 2"} </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to use in the father the value of `indexTab` in `handleSubmitSaveConfigurationsPre` how can I pass that value with the props `onClick={handleSubmit}` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273144/pass-values-from-children-to-parent-component/58273209#58273209

Comment: No, my problem is that I need to pass besides the parameter of the handleSubmit another value that comes from the Child.

Comment: `<Child handleCb={param => parentHandler(param)} />` and from `Child` execute it like `handleCb(param)`

Comment: But what happen with `val`? I need to use the `val`and also the parameter `indexTab` from Child

Comment: Posted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass an aditional parameter to `handleSubmit` first you need to change the function's signature

```
handleSubmit= (val, foo) => {
    console.log(val)//hello
    console.log(foo)
}
```

Now prepare the `callback` pass to your `Child` to expect an aditional parameter

```
return <Child callback={foo => this.handleSubmit(val, foo)} />
```

And from inside `Child` call your `callback`

```
callback('foo')
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `handleSubmit` wrapped inside an anonymous function with `indexTab` as argument.

```
<Button onClick={() => handleOnSubmit(indexTab)}>
```

Parent component

```
<Child
            handleOnSubmit = {(indexTab) => this.handleSubmit(val, indexTab)}
            etc...
```

Comment: I have an error when I pass a parameter to the props `react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type`

Comment: Use handleOnSubmit instead of handleSubmit

Comment: Ok, that was a typo, but how I use then the value of indexTab in handleSubmit function in the Father? as a parameter I only have `val`

Comment: val is the parameter of that function, it has the same value as that of indexTab as you pass it as an argument

Comment: that not solves my problem then. Look in the example. `val` is a var that has another data different from `indexTab` the handle function needs both parameters

Comment: Change the parent component code as the updated answer

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the parent you should do something like.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
state = {
   tabIndex: null
}

handleSubmitSaveConfigurationsPre = val => {
    console.log(val);
    console.log(this.state.tabIndex);
}

setValuleFromChild = value => {
  this.setState({tabIndex: value });
}

<Child handleOnSubmit={this.setValuleFromChild} ...
```

in the children you should do something like:

```
render() {

    const { indexTab,  handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (<Button onClick={() => handleSubmit(indexTab)}> {indexTab !== 2 ? "Save 0 or 1" : "Save 2"} </Button>
    );
```

Comment: But look that my handle on parent has a parameter `this.handleSubmit(val)` I need that `val`and aldo the `indexTab` that comes from the child

Comment: But how I use then in `handleSubmit` function in the parent? as a parameter I only have `val`

Comment: I think you have to use the state. Or, you can pass an object as parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't want to setState again for that.